# How to update existing documents with Spring Data MongoDB type information after type renames?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongo-java

I am using mongodb with spring and I have some subdocuments that are derived from one base class, mongo uses the '_class' property to find out what is the correct type to convert to, but now I have changed the package name and the collection still has documents with old package name, how can I tell mongo what custom conversions to do ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

first of all for next time to decouple your `package/class` name from `_class` variable, use: `@TypeAlias("name")` annotation on your pojo. then `_class` will have the value `"name`"

The easiest solution in my opinion is to update your pojo with `TypeAlias` and update your collection's `_class` field with it's new value

Read about `Type mapping` over here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.type-mapping

Comment: Sometime you need with the `@TypeAlias` to add `@Document(collection="collectionName")` for it to work. I encountered the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57910383/7747942)