# How to aggregate in spring data mongo db a nested object and avoid a PropertyReferenceException?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am creating a new endpoint in springboot that will return simple stats on users generated from an aggregate query in a mongo database. However I get a `PropertyReferenceException`. I have read multiple stackoverflow questions about it, but didn't find one that solved this problem.

We have a mongo data scheme like this:

```js
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5d795993288c3831c8dffe60"), 
"user" : "000001", 
"name" : "test", 
"attributes" : { 
    "brand" : "Chrome",
    "language" : "English" }
}
```

The database is filled with multiple users and we want using Springboot aggregate the stats of users per `brand`. There could be any number of attributes in the `attributes` object.

Here is the aggregation we are doing

```java
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    group("attributes.brand").count().as("number"),
    project("number").and("type").previousOperation()
);

AggregationResults<Stats> groupResults
    = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Profile.class, Stats.class);

return groupResults.getMappedResults();
```

Which produces this mongo query which works:

```js
> db.collection.aggregate([ 
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$attributes.brand" , "number" : { "$sum" : 1}}} ,
{ "$project" : { "number" : 1 , "_id" : 0 , "type" : "$_id"}} ])

{ "number" : 4, "type" : "Chrome" }
{ "number" : 2, "type" : "Firefox" }
```

However when running a simple integration test we get this error:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property brand found for type String! Traversed path: Profile.attributes.
```

From what I understand, it seems that since `attributes` is a `Map<String, String>` there might be a schematic problem. And in the mean time I can't modify the `Profile` object.

**Is there something I am missing in the aggregation, or anything I could change in my `Stats` object?**

For reference, here are the data models we're using, to work with JSON and jackson.

The `Stats` data model:

```java
@Document
public class Stats {

  @JsonProperty
  private String type;

  @JsonProperty
  private int number;

  public Stats() {}

  /* ... */
}
```

The `Profile` data model:

```java
@Document
public class Profiles {

  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty
  private String user;

  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty
  private String name;

  @JsonProperty
  private Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();

  public Stats() {}

  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, which was a combination of two problems:

The `PropertyReferenceException` was indeed caused because `attributes` is a `Map<String, String>` which means there is no schemes for Mongo.

The error message `No property brand found for type String! Traversed path: Profile.attributes.` means that the `Map` object doesn't have a brand property in it.

In order to fix that without touching my orginal `Profile` class, I had to create a new custom class which would map the `attributes` to an attributes object having the properties I want to aggreate on like:

```java
public class StatsAttributes {

  @JsonProperty
  private String brand;

  @JsonProperty
  private String language;

  public StatsAttributes() {}

  /* ... */
}
```

Then I created a custom `StatsProfile` which would leverage my `StatsAttributes` and would be similar to the the original `Profile` object without modifying it.

```java
@Document
public class StatsProfile {

  @JsonProperty
  private String user;

  @JsonProperty
  private StatsAttributes attributes;

  public StatsProfile() {}

  /* ... */
}
```

With that I made disapear my problem with the `PropertyReferenceException` using my new class `StatsAggregation` in the aggregation:

```
AggregationResults<Stats> groupResults 
     = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, StatsProfile.class, Stats.class);
```

However I would not get any results. It seems the query would not find any document in the database. That's where I realied that production mongo objects had the field `"_class: com.company.dao.model.Profile"` which was tied to the `Profile` object.

After some research, for the new `StatsProfile` to work it would need to be a `@TypeAlias("Profile")`. After looking around, I found that I also needed to precise a collection name which would lead to:

```java
@Document(collection = "profile")
@TypeAlias("Profile")
public class StatsProfile {

/* ... */
}
```

And with all that, finally it worked!

> I suppose that's not the prettiest solution, I wish I would not need to create a new Profile object and just consider the `attributes` as a `StatsAttributes.class` somehow in the mongoTemplate query. If anyone knows how to, please share